what's the purpose of the mahāvyāhṛti (Om bhuh bhuvah suvah)
The Gayatri mantra is composed from a verse taken from the Rg-Veda, dedicated to Savitr, the spiritual sun, plus "The great mystical utterance".
I understand why we would want to start every mantra with AUM (the essence of Brahman, the seed of all creation and mantras), however I don't understand why would we utter the three lower Lokas (dimensions) before the actual mantra.
I'm even more confused, because there are even higher dimensions, only uttered in the "extended" Gayatri mantra.
what does "Bhuh Bhuvah Suvah" accomplish when uttered? what is the purpose of declaring those dimensions? what effect happens when these dimensions are uttered?
the Question here, ask a similar answer, with no direct answer
